# How to use discriminated union types in FastAPI body validation? (Union on models)

Tags: python, validation, fastapi, python-typing, pydantic

I know a concept from Typescript called *Discriminated unions*. That's a thing where you put 2 struct (classes, etc) and the type is decided depending on a struct's values. I'm trying to achieve similar thing in *FastAPI* with *Pydantic* validation. There are two different request payloads that I can recieve. Whether it's one or another depends on `accountType` variable. If it's `creative` it should be validated by `RegistrationPayloadCreative` and if it's `brand` it should validate by `RegistrationPayloadBrand`. How do I achieve this? Couldn't find any other solution.

The problem is that it either returns

`unexpected value; permitted: 'creative' (type=value_error.const; given=brand; permitted=('creative',))`

Or it doesn't work at all.

```py
class RegistrationPayloadBase(BaseModel):
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    email: str
    password: str


class RegistrationPayloadCreative(RegistrationPayloadBase):
    accountType: Literal['creative']


class RegistrationPayloadBrand(RegistrationPayloadBase):
    company: str
    phone: str
    vat: str
    accountType: Literal['brand']

class A(BaseModel):
    b: Union[RegistrationPayloadBrand, RegistrationPayloadCreative]

def main():
    A(b={'first_name': 'sdf', 'last_name': 'sdf', 'email': 'sdf', 'password': 'sdfds', 'accountType': 'brand'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Future readers might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71337839/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71545639/17865804) helpful

Answer (score 11):

You should use `__root__` and `parse_obj` instead.

```py
from typing import Union

from pydantic import BaseModel


class PlanetItem(BaseModel):
    id: str
    planet_name: str 
    # ...

class CarItem(BaseModel):
    id: str
    name: str
    # ...

class EitherItem(BaseModel):
    __root__: Union[PlanetItem, CarItem]



@app.get("/items/{item_id}", response_model=EitherItem)
def get_items(item_id):
    return EitherItem.parse_obj(response) # Now you get either PlanetItem or CarItem
```

Credit: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2279#issuecomment-787517707

Comment: What if I want to apply this technique to FastAPI Request body/params? I tried it but it doesn't seem to discriminate between the types

Comment: @Beast That's not a good idea to mix different parameters in the same endpoint. If you insist on doing so, I suggest you to combine the fields into one model and write methods to convert them separately.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is a bit misleading since the problem is that company/phone/vat fields are mandatory in  RegistrationPayloadBrand.

So:

```
 >>> A(b={'first_name': 'sdf', 'last_name': 'sdf', 'email': 'sdf', 'password': 'sdfds', 'accountType': 'brand', 'company':'foo','vat':'bar', 'phone':'baz'}) 
A(b=RegistrationPayloadBrand(first_name='sdf', last_name='sdf',
email='sdf', password='sdfds', company='foo', phone='baz', vat='bar', accountType='brand'))

>>> A(b={'first_name': 'sdf', 'last_name': 'sdf', 'email': 'sdf', 'password': 'sdfds', 'accountType': 'creative'})
A(b=RegistrationPayloadCreative(first_name='sdf', last_name='sdf', email='sdf', password='sdfds', accountType='creative'))
```

Or making them Optional (if payload not necessarily contains those fields)

```
class RegistrationPayloadBrand(RegistrationPayloadBase):
    company: Optional[str]
    phone:   Optional[str]
    vat:     Optional[str]
    accountType: Literal['brand']

>>> A(b={'first_name': 'sdf', 'last_name': 'sdf', 'email': 'sdf', 'password': 'sdfds', 'accountType': 'brand'})
A(b=RegistrationPayloadBrand(first_name='sdf', last_name='sdf', email='sdf', password='sdfds', company=None, phone=None, vat=None, accountType='brand'))

>>> A(b={'first_name': 'sdf', 'last_name': 'sdf', 'email': 'sdf', 'password': 'sdfds', 'accountType': 'creative'})
A(b=RegistrationPayloadCreative(first_name='sdf', last_name='sdf', email='sdf', password='sdfds', accountType='creative'))
```

will solve the problem

Comment: You should use `__root__`. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

You're effectively using a discriminated union. You could make that explicit by specifiying the descriminator with `Field(discriminator='pipeline_name')`. It provides for FastAPI (or rather Pydantic I guess) an explicit criteria on how to decide which of the unionized types the payload is.

```
class A(BaseModel):
    b: Union[RegistrationPayloadBrand, RegistrationPayloadCreative] = Field(discriminator='pipeline_name')
```

https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/unions/#discriminated-unions