# FastAPI multiple dynamic POST parameters

Tags: python, fastapi

I'd like to set up a `POST` route with some dynamic parameters, e.g.:

```
@router.post("/", response_model=MyResponseModel, status_code=201)
def create_foo(
    foo: Union[FooCreate, BarCreate],
    type: FooBarType,
    config: Optional[FooBarConfig],
    session: Session = Depends(get_session),
) -> Any:
```

Depending on the value of `type`, `config` can be different things. For example: 
`type` = `A`, `config` can be `1` or `2` 
`type` = `B`, `config` can be `1` or `3` 
`type` = `C`, `config` is `None`

I know I could handle this manually, but I'd like to keep FastAPI documentation up to date also and have dynamic boxes from where to choose parameters for the request. Is it possible to achieve this somehow or do I need to separate this into multiple POST routes?

Comment: Do you mean dynamic boxes are the boxes inside swagger documentation?

Comment: @danangjoyoo Yes.

Comment: Have you tried creating a set of schemas mapping to each type, and using `Literal['A']` as the entry for `type` to separate the different schemas? You can then create a Union across the three possible request models and have the appropriate validation

Comment: You could use  Discriminated Unions, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71545639/17865804)

Comment: I am already using `Union`. I have two different models I'm validating against: `foo: Union[FooCreate, BarCreate]`. These work as supposed, but both Foo and Bar have a type, Foo is type `Foo` and Bar is type `Bar`. `Foo` can have config values 1 or 2, `Bar` can have values 1 or 3. Should I make own config classes for both `Foo` and `Bar`?

Comment: Basically, I'm asking if there's a way to dynamically update the documentation depending on the type I'm choosing. I could also send the parameter `config` in the request body without any boxes to choose from, I'd just need the document to be up to date, e.g. if I choose a type `A`, I'd need the document to show correctly that the possible options for `config` are `1` or `2`, if I choose a type `B`, I'd need the document to show correctly that the possible options for `config` are `1` or `3` etc.

Comment: I thinks it's not possible for swagger bcs it's a static documentation. You have to refresh the browser manually and its a multilevel function I think. Thats where the frontend framework comes in.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **request._json** field to get the raw payload. It will give you all the fields regardless of the fields define in fastapi models. Dependencies parameters are optional.

Use the below code:

```
from fastapi import Request
@router.post("/yourpath", dependencies=[Depends(auth.custom_authorize)])
async def your_api_method(request: Request, payload:PayloadModel):
           raw_payload = request._json
```