# Accepting different datatypes using Pydantic and FastAPI

Tags: python, types, fastapi, typing, pydantic

I have a use case where I am accepting data of different datatypes - namely `dict, boolean, string, int, list` - from the front end application to the FastAPI backedn using a pydantic model.

My question is how should I design my pydantic model so that it can accept any data type, which can later be used for manipulating the data and creating an API?

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Pino(BaseModel):
    asset:str (The data is coming from the front end ((dict,boolean,string,int,list))  )

@app.post("/api/setAsset")
async def pino_kafka(item: Pino):
    messages = {
        "asset": item.asset
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using different pydantic models depending on the value of the fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71539448/using-different-pydantic-models-depending-on-the-value-of-the-fields)

Comment: No Chris , it dint.I would atleast need 4 types of data to accept this , 1) string 2)list of dictionary 3) dictionary 4) list . If I give Union[dict,list,string,int,bool] only the first two datatypes give the correct output , the string part will not work under this circumstances

Answer (score 3):

Define a custom datatype:

```
from typing import Optional, Union
my_datatype = Union[dict,boolean,string,int,list]
```

In python 3.9 onwards, you don't need Union any-more:

```
my_datatype = dict | boolean | string | int | list
```

Then use it in your model:

```
class Pino(BaseModel):
    asset: my_datatype
```

If you really want "any" datatype, just use "Any":

```
from typing import Any
class Pino(BaseModel):
    asset: Any
```

In any case, I hardly find a use case for this, the whole point of using pydantic is imposing datatypes.

Comment: Thanks for your revert ,  However union will be able to take first two types rite ? which means if I give Union[dict,boolean,string,int,list] , this will only take in either dict or bool

Comment: I think it works also for multiple data types.

Comment: it breaks in the middle : if we give input as list of dictionary for Union[dict,boolean,string,int,list]  , only the dictionary part would be printed

Comment: Use dict[Any,Any] and list[Any], because dict and list are containers of other datatypes. if you really want a list of dictionaries put list[dict[str,str]] or list[dict[Any,Any]], depends on your needs.

Comment: I would atleast need 4 types of data to work , 1) string 2)list of dictionary 3) dictionary 4) list . If I give Union[dict,list,string,int,bool] only the first two datatypes give the correct output , the string part will not work under this circumstances

Comment: When you say list of dictionary and dictionary, a dictionary is also container of datatypes, like dictionary of string-string. Anyway, can you put the trace back or the error you get?

Comment: so ideal situation is union takes in only two data types ,If I consider the above example Union[dict,boolean,string,int,list] , the solution will work only for boolean and dict . To explain in depth , if the incoming data is {'key' : 'value'} or boolean value(true or false) I am able to send a post request , if the input data is List : for ex ['keyword1','keyword2'] or string "name" , I cannot post any data because the union what I defined is only accepting first two fields i.e either dict or boolean , If I interchange the datatype in union then it works for list and string but not (dict,bool)

Comment: Any solution you would propose