# Pydantic response model is a union of models how to know which model is being used

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

Currently I have a pydantic models that handle 3 scenarios as documented below, For FastAPI response model I use a union of these 3 models so that the corresponding model can be used to validate the response fields.

```
class SuccessResponse(BaseModel):
    status: Literal['SUCCESS']
    data: Dict // varies

class FailureResponse(BaseModel):
    status: Literal['FAILED']
    data: Dict // varies

class ErrorResponse(BaseModel):
    status: Literal['ERROR']
    data: Dict //varies

class ResponseModel(BaseModel):
    __root__ = Union[
        SuccessResponse,
        FailureResponse,
        ErrorResponse
    ]
```

in FastAPI I use the response model as the model must be able to validate the response of a method against all three models and return a positive response. But inside the FastAPI route how do I know which model is being returned so that I can parse corresponding data using `SuccessResponse.parse_obj(response)` or the other models in Union. Is there a way to find this out??

Comment: Please have a look at this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71545639/17865804) as well.

Comment: Thanks the first one answers my question