# Initialize one of two Pydantic models depending on an init parameter

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a Pydantic model class `MessageModel` with a version number as [`Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal). Now our requirements have changed and we need another `MessageModel` with a higher version number, because the attributes of the `MessageModel` have changed. I want to have a class, where I can give the version number as an argument to the constructor. Does anyone have an idea?

Here are the models:

```py
from typing import Literal
from pydantic import BaseModel


class MessageModelV1(BaseModel):
    version: Literal[1]
    bar: str
        
class MessageModelV2(BaseModel):
    version: Literal[2]
    foo: str
```

What I want is a class which initializes the right `MessageModel` version:

```py
model = MessageModel(version=2, ...)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using different Pydantic models depending on the value of fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71539448/using-different-pydantic-models-depending-on-the-value-of-fields)

Comment: Not really, in this example fastapi is used, which tries both and one succeeds. But what I need is a class that, when I initialise it, automatically selects the right model.

Comment: Fair enough. Though the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76449131) provides a solution independent from FastAPI. But the question itself was specifically about FastAPI routes, so yours is not exactly a duplicate. I provided a more in-depth answer with two different approaches just for Pydantic below.

Answer (score 8):

## Discriminated union

You can define a [**discriminated union**](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.2/usage/types/unions/#discriminated-unions-aka-tagged-unions) of two or more Pydantic models. This will allow you to instantiate the correct model based on the value of the discriminator field provided in the data.

There are a few slightly different approaches you can take.

---

### Option A: Annotated type alias

Instead of defining a new model that "combines" your existing ones, you define a type alias for the union of those models and use [`typing.Annotated`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Annotated) to add the discriminator information.

```py
# Pydantic v1

from typing import Annotated, Literal, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, parse_obj_as


class MessageModelV1(BaseModel):
    version: Literal[1]
    bar: str


class MessageModelV2(BaseModel):
    version: Literal[2]
    foo: str


MessageModel = Annotated[
    Union[MessageModelV1, MessageModelV2],
    Field(discriminator="version"),
]


data1 = {"version": 1, "bar": "a"}
data2 = {"version": 2, "foo": "b"}
obj1 = parse_obj_as(MessageModel, data1)
obj2 = parse_obj_as(MessageModel, data2)
print(obj1, type(obj1))  # version=1 bar='a' <class '__main__.MessageModelV1'>
print(obj2, type(obj2))  # version=2 foo='b' <class '__main__.MessageModelV2'>
```

##### Pros

- Minimal additional code, just a type definition.
- You get an actual instance of one of the original models.
- Static type checkers can infer the type as a union of the original models. (This gives IDEs the ability to provide *some* useful auto-suggestions.)

##### Cons

- You cannot directly instantiate `MessageModel` because it is a typing construct and not a model class.
- To construct an instance you must use the additional [`parse_obj_as`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/models/#parsing-data-into-a-specified-type) function.
- There is no way to statically determine, *which exact* model will come out after parsing because it depends on the data.

##### UPDATE: Pydantic v2

Very similar but using the [`TypeAdapter`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.2/usage/type_adapter/) instead of `parse_as_obj`:

```py
# Pydantic v2

from typing import Annotated, Literal, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, TypeAdapter


class MessageModelV1(BaseModel):
    version: Literal[1]
    bar: str


class MessageModelV2(BaseModel):
    version: Literal[2]
    foo: str


MessageModel = TypeAdapter(Annotated[
    Union[MessageModelV1, MessageModelV2],
    Field(discriminator="version"),
])


data1 = {"version": 1, "bar": "a"}
data2 = {"version": 2, "foo": "b"}
obj1 = MessageModel.validate_python(data1)
obj2 = MessageModel.validate_python(data2)
print(obj1, type(obj1))  # version=1 bar='a' <class '__main__.MessageModelV1'>
print(obj2, type(obj2))  # version=2 foo='b' <class '__main__.MessageModelV2'>
```

Unfortunately, as of now, Mypy seems unable to infer the type of the resulting model instances correctly, while Pyright does.

---

### Option B: Custom root type

You define a new model and set its [`__root__` type](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/models/#custom-root-types) to the discriminated union between of the original models.

Then you can customize it to the degree you see fit, in order to make instance of it "feel" like any of the original underlying models.

In the following example I overrode the `__init__` method so that you can initialize it like you described in your question. I also made it [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) via the underlying root model, and I added custom [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) and [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) methods so that instances are displayed as though they are of the underlying root type.

```py
# Pydantic v1

from collections.abc import Iterator
from typing import Any, Literal, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class MessageModelV1(BaseModel):
    version: Literal[1]
    bar: str


class MessageModelV2(BaseModel):
    version: Literal[2]
    foo: str


MessageType = Union[MessageModelV1, MessageModelV2]


class MessageModel(BaseModel):
    __root__: MessageType = Field(discriminator="version")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        super().__init__(__root__=kwargs)

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[tuple[str, Any]]:  # type: ignore[override]
        yield from self.__root__

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.__root__)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return repr(self.__root__)
```

With the same demo data, you now get slightly different results:

```py
# Pydantic v1

obj1 = MessageModel(version=1, bar="a")
obj2 = MessageModel(version=2, foo="b")
print(obj1, type(obj1))  # version=1 bar='a' <class '__main__.MessageModel'>
print(obj2, type(obj2))  # version=2 foo='b' <class '__main__.MessageModel'>

print(hasattr(obj1, "__root__"))  # True
print(hasattr(obj1, "bar"))       # False
print(hasattr(obj1, "version"))   # False
```

You'll notice that the type of the object is of course the new `MessageModel` now and not one of the underlying original models.

Also, without doing more customization, instances will only have the `__root__` field pointing to an instance of the underlying model and *not* have that model's actual fields. If you want to pass on [attribute access](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access) to the root model, you would have to override `__getattr__`/`__setattr__`:

```py
# Pydantic v1

...

class MessageModel(BaseModel):
    __root__: MessageType = Field(discriminator="version")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        super().__init__(__root__=kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, name: str) -> Any:
        if name == "__root__":
            return self.__root__
        return getattr(self.__root__, name)

    def __setattr__(self, name: str, value: Any) -> None:
        if name == "__root__":
            self.__root__ = value
        setattr(self.__root__, name, value)

    ...
```

```py
# Pydantic v1

obj1 = MessageModel(version=1, bar="a")

print(obj1.version)  # 1
print(obj1.bar)      # a
```

##### Pros

- Direct instantiation is possible because you are dealing with an actual model class.
- Lots of options for customization and additional validation.

##### Cons

- Without any customization you will always deal with a "proxy" model and its `__root__` field will point to the "actual" model.
- Making the outer model feel/behave like one of the underlying models takes a lot of additional boilerplate. You could probably factor all/most of it out into a separate mix-in class, but the code needs to be written nonetheless.
- You might "forget" that you are dealing with the proxy model, not with the root model, and then run into unexpected results. (For example, try to call `obj1.dict()` with the last example and look at the output.)
- The type inferred by static analysis will always be `MessageModel`.

##### PS

You could hack around the fact that the outer `MessageModel` is not actually a subtype of the underlying models with [`typing.TYPE_CHECKING`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING) a bit. Example:

```py
# Pydantic v1

from typing import Any, Literal, Union, TYPE_CHECKING
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class MessageModelV1(BaseModel):
    version: Literal[1]
    bar: str


class MessageModelV2(BaseModel):
    version: Literal[2]
    foo: str


MessageType = Union[MessageModelV1, MessageModelV2]

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    class MessageModel(MessageModelV1, MessageModelV2):
        pass
else:
    class MessageModel(BaseModel):
        __root__: MessageType = Field(discriminator="version")

        def __init__(self, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
            super().__init__(__root__=kwargs)

        ...

obj1 = MessageModel(version=1, bar="a")
```

From a static analysis point of view, `MessageModel` is now a subtype of the other two, which means your IDE would give you the insights accordingly. Type in `obj1.` and PyCharm for example will suggest both the attributes `foo` and `bar`. Typing-wise this makes it essentially equivalent to the `Union` alias approach (Option A).

But of course this is a lie since the actual *runtime* `MessageModel` is not a subclass of those two. But if you know exactly what interface you need to make it "feel" like a subclass, you can make it work.

I would not recommend going that far with the obfuscation.

##### UPDATE: Pydantic v2

Very similar but using the [`RootModel`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.2/usage/models/#rootmodel-and-custom-root-types) instead:

```py
# Pydantic v2

from collections.abc import Iterator
from typing import Any, Literal, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, RootModel


class MessageModelV1(BaseModel):
    version: Literal[1]
    bar: str


class MessageModelV2(BaseModel):
    version: Literal[2]
    foo: str


MessageType = Union[MessageModelV1, MessageModelV2]


class MessageModel(RootModel):
    root: MessageType = Field(discriminator="version")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        super().__init__(root=kwargs)

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[tuple[str, Any]]:  # type: ignore[override]
        yield from self.root

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.root)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return repr(self.root)


obj1 = MessageModel(version=1, bar="a")
obj2 = MessageModel(version=2, foo="b")
print(obj1, type(obj1))  # version=1 bar='a' <class '__main__.MessageModel'>
print(obj2, type(obj2))  # version=2 foo='b' <class '__main__.MessageModel'>

print(hasattr(obj1, "root"))     # True
print(hasattr(obj1, "bar"))      # False
print(hasattr(obj1, "version"))  # False
```

---

### Option C: Union field + proxy constructor

Essentially based on Option B, but instead of going through all that trouble of defining a proxy-interface for the nested model, you just write a custom constructor function that *looks* like a class, and make it instantiate the outer model, but return just its `__root__` value:

```py
# Pydantic v1

from typing import Any, Literal, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class MessageModelV1(BaseModel):
    version: Literal[1]
    bar: str


class MessageModelV2(BaseModel):
    version: Literal[2]
    foo: str


MessageType = Union[MessageModelV1, MessageModelV2]


class OuterMessageModel(BaseModel):
    __root__: MessageType = Field(discriminator="version")


def MessageModel(**kwargs: Any) -> MessageType:
    return OuterMessageModel.parse_obj(kwargs).__root__


obj1 = MessageModel(version=1, bar="a")
obj2 = MessageModel(version=2, foo="b")
print(obj1, type(obj1))  # version=1 bar='a' <class '__main__.MessageModelV1'>
print(obj2, type(obj2))  # version=2 foo='b' <class '__main__.MessageModelV2'>
```

##### Pros

- Fairly simple; not a lot of code.
- Direct instantiation is possible (albeit via a proxy-constructor).
- You get an actual instance of one of the original models.
- Static type checkers can infer the type as a union of the original models. (This gives IDEs the ability to provide *some* useful auto-suggestions.)

##### Cons

- The constructor function looks like a "fake" class. (Though this is a fairly common approach; see for example the Pydantic [`Field`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.9/pydantic/fields.py#L222) function.)
- There is still no way to statically determine, *which exact* model will come out after parsing because it depends on the data.

##### UPDATE: Pydantic v2

Very similar but using the [`RootModel`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.2/usage/models/#rootmodel-and-custom-root-types) instead:

```py
# Pydantic v2

from typing import Any, Literal, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, RootModel


class MessageModelV1(BaseModel):
    version: Literal[1]
    bar: str


class MessageModelV2(BaseModel):
    version: Literal[2]
    foo: str


MessageType = Union[MessageModelV1, MessageModelV2]


class OuterMessageModel(RootModel):
    root: MessageType = Field(discriminator="version")


def MessageModel(**kwargs: Any) -> MessageType:
    return OuterMessageModel.model_validate(kwargs).root


obj1 = MessageModel(version=1, bar="a")
obj2 = MessageModel(version=2, foo="b")
print(obj1, type(obj1))  # version=1 bar='a' <class '__main__.MessageModelV1'>
print(obj2, type(obj2))  # version=2 foo='b' <class '__main__.MessageModelV2'>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your detailed answer, I wasn't expecting something so detailed. Your second suggestion with the root type looks like something I am looking for. 
But as you mentioned, the programmer has to use the __root__ as a proxy. It would be nicer if the MessageModel had the attributes foo or bar, with annotation for the interpreter.

I had already found the first possibility parse_obj_as, but I don't find it so pretty.

Comment: @Phil997 I added another option/variation to my answer. Maybe you'll prefer that one. I don't think there is a "perfect" way to accomplish this without any drawbacks.

Comment: Hey @DaniilFajnberg, I'm not able to call __init__ method, ```class CompositeKey(RootModel):
    root: str

    def __init__(self, **kwargs) -> None:
        print('------------------------------')
        super().__init__(root=kwargs)```

Any idea what's missing in this simple implementation?